# How can I make a Chrome Extenstion that runs when a specific button @ a specific URL is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, button, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that scrapes the names of instructors on a school sponsered website used to pick classes. I would use content scripts that run on a specifically matched URL, but the info that I need to extract may or may not be on the page at one specific time due to one being able to change the view of the window without changing the URL. I need to extract this info and show it in the popup of the extenstion. So my questions are:

1) How can I added a listener that runs the script ONLY when the user searches for the info I am looking for

2) How should I structure my files/what Chrome Extenstion API structures should I use to not only scrape this info, but then also display it in a popup

One could be in the Class Schedule, Search, Add, ect tab without changing the URL
[Here is what the page looks like to better show the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PpPT.png)

I would need to be ablt to extract the info AFTER the green search button is pressed by a user
[Here is another view, the window where one would search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qXWH.png)

URL in question: https://www.spire.umass.edu/psp/heproda/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/SA_LEARNER_SERVICES.SSS_STUDENT_CENTER.GBL?FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.HCCC_ACADEMIC_RECORDS.HC_SSS_STUDENT_CENTER&IsFolder=false&IgnoreParamTempl=FolderPath%2cIsFolder

Comment: Generally this is done by making the content script always run on that site URLs and using MutationObserver inside to check for all subsequently added DOM elements. Or it can use `setInterval` to recheck the page periodically.

Comment: @wOxxOm okay Ill give that a try and let you know if i figure it out. Thanks!